# how to use encoding='utf-8-sig' with json.loads()?

Tags: python, json, utf-8

I found some other questions about this but the solutions don't work and/or I don't understand them.

code is like this:

```
file_data = {}
with open(path) as open_file:
    data = open_file.read()
try:
    file_data = json.loads(data)
except:
    try:
        file_data = json.loads(data, encoding='utf-8-sig')
    except:
        print("this gets printed")
```

file being read is a bit like this, notice the degree ° mark which could be the issue?

`{ "name": "something", "temperature": "44°", "sensor": "model_xyz" }`

file shows in notepad++ as UTF-8-BOM

Error I get is: **KeyError: 'name'**

File output when printed in python has ï»¿ in front of it.

Why doesn't this work: json.loads(data, encoding='utf-8-sig') ?

Tried encoding='utf-8-sig', doesn't seem to do anything, json.loads(data) doesn't find anything in the file.

Comment: Catching and suppressing errors makes this more difficult to work out. `"temperature": 44°` isn't valid JSON. `44` is an integer, but adding that degree sign makes it invalid -  because why would a serialization protocol know what a degree is? If you made it a string, `"44°"` then you'd have something valid. So, if that example you show is the JSON file, whatever wrote is is wrong.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, It has "" around it

Comment: I think I fixed it by adding , encoding='utf-8-sig' in this way:
with open(path, encoding='utf-8-sig') as open_file:

Comment: JSON itself doesn't know about utf-8-sig. Its several bytes you can put on the front of s file to distinguish between UTF-8, UTF-16 and byte order. It should be okay to put the encoding in the open call:` with open(path, endoing="utf-8-sig") as open_file: file_data = json.load(open_file)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) and [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) don't take an *encoding* parameter.  It should be specified when opening the file for reading and writing.

According to [RFC 8259 - The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259):

> [8.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-8.1).
> Character Encoding
>
> JSON text exchanged between systems that are not part of a closed ecosystem MUST be encoded using UTF-8 [[RFC3629](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3629)].
>
> Previous specifications of JSON have not required the use of UTF-8 when transmitting JSON text.  However, the vast majority of JSON-based software implementations have chosen to use the UTF-8 encoding, to the extent that it is the only encoding that achieves interoperability.
>
> Implementations MUST NOT add a byte order mark (U+FEFF) to the beginning of a networked-transmitted JSON text.  In the interests of interoperability, implementations that parse JSON texts MAY ignore the presence of a byte order mark rather than treating it as an error.

So, for reading a file use the following, which "in the interests of interoperability" will remove a byte order mark, if present:

```py
with open(filename, encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

And for writing use:

```py
with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    data = json.dump(data, f)
```

If you have a JSON byte string (a Python `bytes` object), `json.loads` will default decode with `utf-8-sig`:

```py
>>> import json
>>> data = '{"name": "马克"}'.encode('utf-8-sig')
>>> data
b'\xef\xbb\xbf{"name": "\xe9\xa9\xac\xe5\x85\x8b"}'
>>> json.loads(data)
{'name': '马克'}
```

But if for some reason your JSON data is encoded in another encoding, decode it first:

```py
>>> import json
>>> data = '{"name": "马克"}'.encode('chinese')
>>> data
b'{"name": "\xc2\xed\xbf\xcb"}'
>>> json.loads(data.decode('chinese'))
{'name': '马克'}
```